# Error C2682 cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'boost::exception_ptr' to 'const T *'

Tags: exception, boost, boost-asio, dynamic-cast, asio

I'm getting this error when i try to convert `boost::exception_ptr` to `asioThreadException`.

AsioThread.cpp file:

```
    catch(...)
    {
        boost::exception_ptr inner = boost::current_exception();
        if(ExceptionHelper::Contains<AsioThreadException>(inner))
        {
            boost::rethrow_exception(inner);
        }
        else 
        {
         
        }
   }
```

And my ExceptionHelper.h file contains:

```
template <typename T>
static bool Contains(boost::exception_ptr exception)
{
    const T* exceptType = dynamic_cast<const T*>(exception);
    return (exceptType != 0);

}
```

And i'm getting below error:

> Error C2682 cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'boost::exception_ptr' to 'const T *'

Answer (score 0):

`boost::exception_ptr` (and `std:exception_ptr`) APIs do not support what you are doing, their actual types are 'unspecified'.  But I'm not sure why you are doing this as the catch specifications do this for you:

```
catch (AsioThreadException& e) {
    throw;
}
catch (...) {
    //
}
```